# CSV File is not getting downloaded in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, csv

am trying to download a CSV file in my code i have the following controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/navdb/group/{groupIdent}/edit/export/download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String navdbGroupExport( @RequestParam(value = "list[]") List<String> list,@PathVariable String groupIdent,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(groupIdent);
                System.out.println(list);
                response.setContentType("text/csv");
                String reportName = groupIdent+".csv";
                System.out.println(reportName);
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+reportName);

                Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    String outputString = (String) iter.next();
                    System.out.println(outputString);
                    response.getOutputStream().print(outputString);
                }
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "PASS";
        }
```

and my jquery is as follows

```
function exportData() {
    var savedValues = $("#selected-navdb-list>option").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    });
    var groupIdent = $('#navdb-group').find(":selected").text();
    alert(groupIdent);
    var navdbs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < savedValues.length; i++) {
        navdbs.push(savedValues[i]);
    }
    alert(navdbs);
    $.ajax({
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/navdb/group/" + groupIdent + "/edit/export/download",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            list: navdbs
        },
        success: function (obj) {
            alert(obj);
            if (obj == "PASS") {
                alert("pass");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error occurred while fetching the navdb's list.");
        }
    });
}
```

i dont find any problem with my code am not sure why is it not getting downloaded not sure if i missed something

when i tried printing the response i was shocked to see that response that has come to success block had the values which i have appended to response object

how can i download the CSV file ???
please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Since you are writing data to the response stream directly, your method should not have `@ResponseBody` annotation or the `String` return type.  It should simply be `@RequestMapping(...) public String navdbGroupExport(...)`.

Comment: I have pasted the tested code, working fine for me. Please implement something similar to this. Plz accept the answer if it helps you!

Comment: Let me know if you need further assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not `return` any string value, instead keep the method return type `void`. Check the sample code I pasted, your implementation has to follow this pattern.

```
@Controller
public class SpringFileDownload {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/downoadCSV/{groupIdent}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadAttachment(
            @RequestParam("listData") List<String> listData, @PathVariable String groupIdent
            HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
        try {
            servletResponse.setContentType("text/csv");
            servletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myfile.csv\"");
            OutputStream outputStream = servletResponse.getOutputStream();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            boolean firstTime = true;
            for(String str:listData){
                if(firstTime){
                    firstTime = false;
                } else {
                    stringBuffer.append(',');
                }
                stringBuffer.append(str);
            }           
            outputStream.write(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return;

        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            servletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
            servletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
            servletResponse.getWriter().print("{\"error_message\": \"Error Occured!!!\"}");
        }
    }
}
```

File download code in JQuery using IFrame:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/download/" + groupIdent,
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        listData: navdbs.toString();
    },
    success: function (obj) {
        $("body").append("<iframe src='" + obj.url+ "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error occurred while fetching the navdb's list.");
    } });
```

I have assumed `navdbs` as an array `['asas', 'asasrwer', 'sgdhd']`

Test it from browser first by hitting the url, it should show you the download popup.

My recommendation is instead of depending upon the `"string"` value to detect success or failure, use the `http status code`. If at all there is a need to return string, you can use `servletResponse.getWriter().print("your_text")`. This should work for you.

Feel free to comment if you encounter further issue!

Comment: Thanks for your response... but am not sure, this looks too complicated for me, i can remove return type string in the controller but what's wrong with my rest of the code, ideally that should work right ??

Comment: what should i send for attachment id ??? my application is only for our internal usage so much of security is not needed actually, simple code which can download a CSV or Excel should help me

Comment: `attachment id` you ignore. Let me compose a simple example and paste in there!

Comment: Updated with the simpler example.

Comment: This looks very clear... but nothing is happening i mean, the file is not getting downloaded.......

Comment: How are you testing it? Hit the url from browser, `no js`. Check consoles of your IDE as well as Browser And let me know. I hope your spring setup is right, if not resolve that first. You can also launch the app in debug mode and trace through what is going wrong!

Comment: hey if i try it from the request mapping am able to download but when i try calling it from js its not getting downloaded :(

Comment: i have a path variable which is supposed to be the name of the CSV and array list to controller, the array list has to be written to CSV and it should download the CSV with the name

Comment: actually there is a problem with my request mapping i guess.. because when just give /download as request mapping and try accessing directly the url... am able to download the file.... but with same request mapping when i try clicking on the export button am not able to download.... am not sure how to solve this

Comment: I have updated the post with JQuery Ajax code, hope it helps you!

Comment: again something went wrong :( .... it says No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/corept/navdb/group/Manasa/undefined] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: Hi @Manu, just a suggestion, please revise the Spring MVC concepts. These are small issues.  URL Request mapping is something you should be able to resolve by yourself.

Comment: Hey yeah got it resolved... thank you so much for your help